# Any jQuery sliders that can transaition plain HTML & not images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml, slider

I have a section on my site very similar to this site: http://www.royalways.com/index.html however I notice that their sections that are transitioned are all images & all the sliders I have found so far only work with images as well.

I was hoping to keep my sections on my site as plain HTML for the added SEO benefits (even though a transition effect would be very nice)... so was wondering if there was anyway to transition between plain html? Any jQuery plugins or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try jquery tools.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html

here is the link to the scroller section.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/autoscroll.html

I use the plugin to scroll plain html on this site.

http://www.nonhodgkinsztoa.com/

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you know if I will be able to get it to work how I want or does it only work similar to how it does on your site?